# Where to put a dummy variable in GARCH in Mean Code of Tsay and get output?

Tags: time-series, volatility

I need to test the impact of dummy variable in GARCH in Mean code provided by Tsay -http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41202/sp2013/garchM.R

Where should I add the dummy variable in this code to run it?

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: Can someone help?